# Calculate the exponential of Natural Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

In Haskell, using the declaration, how do you calculate the exponentiation of natural numbers `n` and `m`, `n^m`?

```
exponential :: Nat -> Nat
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate anything else with this type? You can implement exponentiation in terms of multiplication, and you can implement multiplication in terms of addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft it by implementing addition and multiplication first:

```hs
plus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus n Zero = n                    -- n + 0 = n
plus n (Succ m) = Succ (plus n m)  -- n + (m + 1) = 1 + (n + m)

mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult n Zero = Zero                   -- n * 0 = 0
mult n (Succ m) = plus n (mult n m)  -- n * (m + 1) = n + n * m

expo :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
expo n Zero = Succ Zero              -- n^0 = 1
expo n (Succ m) = mult n (expo n m)  -- n^(m + 1) = n * n^m
```

Note that the type for exponentiation as you described it should be `Nat -> Nat -> Nat`, instead of `Nat -> Nat`.